# Unable to use a Google font on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my code:

```
img.onload = function() {

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 480);

  ctx.lineWidth  = 4;
  ctx.font = "3em 'Lato'";
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

  var text = 'Custom Text';
  text = text.toUpperCase();
  x = canvas.width/2;
  y = canvas.height - canvas.height/4.5;
  ctx.strokeText(text, x, y);
  ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
}
```

The font on the canvas is not Lato. After reading other answers, I thought it may be because I am not using it on any other HTML element but then I also added a heading that uses the `Lato` font. Is there anything else that can cause this issue?

Comment: In addition to the malformed font description problem, you must wait for the font to load. Annoyingly, browsers do not include a `font.onload` callback, but Google has this [workaround](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader) that gives you a callback when the Google font is fully loaded & ready to draw onto the canvas. ;-)

Comment: @markE I thought using the font on a DOM element will load the font and since the element uses the font correctly, I thought it was loaded properly. :)

Comment: Like images, Fonts are allowed to load asynchronously. When the browser becomes aware that the font has loaded, it re-renders the page with the desired fonts. But by that time the canvas has already been rendered with the substitute font. The browser will not re-render with canvas content. Rendering (or re-rendering) canvas content when the font is fully available is something you must do.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a [working example based on the MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font). What's missing from the MDN example is `document.fonts.add`:

```js
const image = document.getElementById("canvas");

let myFont = new FontFace(
  "Pangolin",
  "url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pangolin/v6/cY9GfjGcW0FPpi-tWMfN79z4i6BH.woff2)"
);

myFont.load().then((font) => {
  document.fonts.add(font);
  console.log("Font loaded");
  var ctx = image.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "#292929";
  ctx.font = "30px Pangolin";
  ctx.fillText("A chicken", 0, 30);
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code before starting using the canvas:

```
var f = new FontFace("Lato", /* url */);
  f.load().then(function() {
    // Ready to use the font in a canvas context
});
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font

Comment: this is great in theory but a *working* example would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ctx.font = "3em Lato";
```

Comment: is it an answer at all? the same line exists in the question itself... how this can help to answer the question?

Comment: the question is ``ctx.font = "3em 'Lato'";``...I think the problem is the quote..

Comment: this is great in theory but a *working* example would be fantastic

Answer (score 0):

I think you may just have a malformed `font` string. Try removing the quotes around the font-family:

```
ctx.font = "3em Lato";
```

Comment: This is what I used at first but I still could not get the font to load.

Comment: this is great in theory but a *working* example would be fantastic