# How do I load Google Fonts in a webpage for CanvasAPI?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, fonts, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use google fonts in CanvasAPI but when I do so, I need to reload the page so the font actually appears. I'm wondering how to use google fonts without needing to reload the page in CanvasAPI.

I put
`font-family: Rubik`
for the canvas's styling. I also searched google and Stack Overflow but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please read these articles: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/Minimal-Reproducible-Example and try to incorporate them into this question.

Comment: What's CanvasAPI? Is that actually a package/library of some sort, or are you referring to the generic HTML5 canvas API? If the latter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66094821/6243352). If not, please clarify what library you're working with and provide a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Hermanboxcar, I've read that already. What part of the question do you not understand? CanvasAPI is when you use the canvas tag to draw sketches.

Comment: I know that, but not specifying HTML5 canvas makes it sound like you are using an API or library (as in something like jQuery or a REST API) As the Community Bot suggested, provide us with some of your HTML and CSS, and maybe add a screenshot of what you saw, compared with a screenshot of text in the font you want.

Answer (score 0):

Loading fonts dynamically can cause delays in rendering, especially if the font files are fetched asynchronously, so to fix your problem let's try some steps:

1. **Preloading Fonts**: You can preload the fonts in the `<head>` section of your HTML to ensure they are available when CanvasAPI starts rendering.

   ```html
   <link rel="preload" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap" as="style" onload="this.onload=null;this.rel='stylesheet'">
   <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap"></noscript>
   ```
2. **Font Display**: Use the `font-display` property in your CSS to control how the fonts are displayed while loading. The `swap` value, for example, displays the fallback font until the Google Font is loaded, then swaps it in.

   ```css
   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Rubik';
     font-display: swap;
     src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap');
   }
   ```
3. **Using a Web Font Loader**: You can use it to load Google Fonts asynchronously and execute code after the fonts are loaded.

   First, include the Web Font Loader script in your HTML:

   ```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js"></script>
   ```

   Then, in your JavaScript code:

   ```js
   WebFont.load({
     google: {
       families: ['Rubik']
     },
     active: function() {
       // Code to manipulate CanvasAPI once fonts are loaded
     }
   });
   ```

And don't forget to check if your internet connection is not too slow!